# How to Create Hashmap in android 

Tags: java, android, hashmap

i want to create hashmap.how its possible
**i want this type hashmap as below**

```
{Question=how are you, friend=mack}
{Question=how are you, friend=jack}
{Question=hello, friend=mack}
{Question=hello, friend=jack}
```

how its get this type of map from below code

```
map_friend = webservice.getFrend(); //{0=Mack, 1=jack}
map_QUE = webservice.getQuestion();//{0=How are you, 1=hello}

int RQSize = map_QUE.size();
int Isize = map_ITEM.size();
     for (i = 0; i < RQSize; i++) 
     {

                rate_map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        final String val = map_QUE.get(i);

        rate_map.put("Question", val);
        mylist.add(rate_map);


        for (j = 0; j < Isize; j++) 
                {
                     rate_map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();

            final String val1 = map_friend.get(j);
            rate_map1.put("friend", val1);
            mylist1.add(rate_map1);
        }

    }
```

mylist and mylist1 is arraylist

Comment: I don't understand the question. Do you want to know how to create a list of maps?

Comment: yes i edited my question again

Comment: what's the problem with what you have? It's no good to us if you don't tell us what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you want to know how to declare a list of maps. You can do it like this:

```
List<Map<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
List<Map<String, String>> mylist1 = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Android has HaspMap datastructre. See the below code and get idea:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
list.put("Question=hello", "friend=jack");
```